# Add ID or CLASS to select.option in JHTML select lists

Tags: html, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I have this code and I'm trying to add an id="" or class="" to each of these 2 select.option .... can somebody give me a hand please, I tried different ways and positions but it just doesn't work...

```
$status []=JHTML::_('select.option','1',JText::_('Yes'),'id','title');
$status []=JHTML::_('select.option','0',JText::_('No'),'id','title');
```

On site this code looks like

```
<label for="show_map1">Yes</label>
<label for="show_map0">No</label>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<label for="show_map1" id="map_yes">Yes</label>
<label for="show_map0" id="map_no">No</label>
```

Can somebody give me a hand please?

Thank you

Comment: How are you creating the list itself? A `select.booleanList` will produce labels with ids by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$manufacturers = array ('Nike','Adi');
$lists['manufacturers'] = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $manufacturers, 'virtuemart_manufacturer_id', 'class="inputbox"', 'value', 'text', $product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id );



//$manufacturers is the options array
//virtuemart_manufacturer_id is the id and name of the filed
//'class="inputbox"' you can add additional class here
//$product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id is used for set default selection like Nike or Adi here.

echo $lists['manufacturers'];
```

Hope its help ..